# Flexmojos-maven-plugin - How to configure multiple source mxml files to generate multiple swf files?

Tags: maven, apache-flex, mxml, flexmojos, flex-mojos

**Current working code:**

I am able to build a flex project using flexmojos-maven-plugin successfully. However, I can only provide one 'sourceFile' under my plugin configuration. Refer below my working pom.xml, which builds Main.mxml file correctly from 'src' directory. It generates the 'swf' file for Main.mxml successfully:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>TA_UI_Test2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>swf</packaging>
    <name>TA_UI_Test2 Flex</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>playerglobal</artifactId>
            <version>10-3.3.0.4852</version>
            <type>swc</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>rpc</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1.21328</version>
            <type>swc</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.3958</version>
            <type>swc</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>mx</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0.19786</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
                <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceFile>Main.mxml</sourceFile>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <storepass/>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
                        <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0.3958</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

**Problem description:**

Now I have got multiple other mxml files under my 'src' directory, i.e. all mxml files under one single 'src' directory. How do I add them in above plugin, which only expects one single name in sourceFile configuration?

**Things I have tried:**

I tried copy-pasting multiple blocks of flexmojos-maven-plugin, and each of them having different sourceFile specified. However, that does not help, because maven just generates the final 'swf' file from the last block of flexmojos-maven-plugin. For eg. if first plugin block has sourceFile Main.mxml, and second plugin block has sourceFile Secondary.mxml, then the 'swf' will be generated for Secondary.mxml only, not for Main.mxml.

Could you provide any other suggestions to generate individual swf files for respective mxml files using single pom/maven build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a lot of R&D, trying a few hacks, and based on valuable suggestion of Christofer Dutz on [this](http://apache-flex-development.2333347.n4.nabble.com/Configure-multiple-source-mxml-files-to-generate-multiple-swf-files-td65109.html) forum, finally a clean solution is available for above problem. Here is the updated pom.xml, which will generate the individual swf files for provided source files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>TA_UI_Test2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>swf</packaging>
    <name>TA_UI_Test2 Flex</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>playerglobal</artifactId>
            <version>10-3.3.0.4852</version>
            <type>swc</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>rpc</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1.21328</version>
            <type>swc</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.3958</version>
            <type>swc</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>mx</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0.19786</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
                <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <storepass></storepass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile-swf</id> <!--DO NOT change this ID, else the plugin execution will fail.-->
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceFile>File1.mxml</sourceFile>
                            <debug>true</debug>
                            <output>${basedir}/target/File1.swf</output>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile-swf</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile-swf-2</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceFile>File2.mxml</sourceFile>
                            <debug>true</debug>
                            <output>${basedir}/target/File2.swf</output>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile-swf</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile-swf-3</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceFile>File3.mxml</sourceFile>
                            <debug>true</debug>
                            <output>${basedir}/target/File3.swf</output>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile-swf</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
                        <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0.3958</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

**Important note**: You have to provide the ID of any one of the executions as 'default-compile-swf', without which it would fail to identify the source file. For more information on the error which it will throw, refer to the link of the forum given above where I was discussing the same.

Hope this helps someone someday :)